# Android - My SMS no longer ask when send service SMS

Tags: android, sms

Android 5.0 will ask when SMS apps tries to send a service SMS ( 8xxx or 1xxx or something else ...)
But mine is no longer ask me when send it.
I tried to restore my phone twice today but it's not help.

Somebody can please give a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going to Settings>Apps>"Your SMS app" and then clear default?

Comment: Look like it won't help. I also reset my phone but no luck here.